# How to interpret hex number byte array from left shift binary sum?

Tags: java, c#, android, hex, byte

My android application is receiving an array of data bytes that is sent from a C# application. I need to interpret those bytes.

In C# application, there are 16 check boxes (Bit0 to Bit15) in form and the code shows processing of those checkbox result.

```
ushort flag = (ushort)(
                (Bit0.Checked ? (1 << 0) : (0)) +
                (Bit1.Checked ? (1 << 1) : (0)) +
                (Bit2.Checked ? (1 << 2) : (0)) +
                (Bit3.Checked ? (1 << 3) : (0)) +
                (Bit4.Checked ? (1 << 4) : (0)) +
                (Bit5.Checked ? (1 << 5) : (0)) +
                (Bit6.Checked ? (1 << 6) : (0)) +
                (Bit7.Checked ? (1 << 7) : (0)) +
                (Bit8.Checked ? (1 << 8) : (0)) +
                (Bit9.Checked ? (1 << 9) : (0)) +
                (Bit10.Checked ? (1 << 10) : (0)) +
                (Bit11.Checked ? (1 << 11) : (0)) +
                (Bit12.Checked ? (1 << 12) : (0)) +
                (Bit13.Checked ? (1 << 13) : (0)) +
                (Bit14.Checked ? (1 << 14) : (0)) +
                (Bit15.Checked ? (1 << 15) : (0)));
```

`flag` is passed to the function described below and then it is sent to my Android application.

```
    public static void setFlag(List<Byte> data, ushort flag)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            int t = flag >> (i * 8);
            data.Add((byte)(t & 0x00FF));
        }
    }
```

In Android application, the data is received as an array of 4 bytes and then it is converted to decimal

```
public String bytesToAscii(byte[] data) {
    String str = new String(data);
    return str.trim();
}

// This returns the decimal
Integer.parseInt(bytesToAscii(flag), 16)
```

Let's say for example, when Bit13 was checked in the C# application; the Andriod app receives an array of 4 bytes which represents hex numbers:

```
flag[0] = 0x30;
flag[1] = 0x30;
flag[2] = 0x32;
flag[3] = 0x30;
```

It is converted to `0020` and it is then converted to decimal:

```
Integer.parseInt(bytesToAscii(flag), 16); // 32
```

I need to parse `32` to figure out Bit13 was selected. Bit13 is just an example for 32. I need to figure out which one or more Bit (0 to 15) are selected.

Comment: Why do you receive the data as an array of 4 Bytes instead of 2 Bytes?

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 8?  If you have two bytes then data[0] << 8 + data[1] to form an int16.  Then your for loop loops through 16 bits and looks like the reverse of 'flag' code.

Comment: @JornVernee he's adding 2 Bytes (0 and 1) - but I don't get the whole process of converting...

Comment: I don't know the reason why I'm receiving 4 bytes instead of 2 bytes. I don't fully understand the C# part as it is developed by the other developers. Fortunately, I got their source code. According to `setFlag()`, it is 2 bytes, but in their system documentation, the size length is `N * 2` bytes. That's why I'm receiving 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a bit is set, you can do a bitwise AND with that bit. Then check if the result is equal to 0. If it isn't, the bit was set.

e.g.

```
00100110
00000010     // checks the second bit
-------- &
00000010     // result != 0, so the bit was set
```

---

A `char` is unsigned 16 bits, so you could use that to store the result.

`0020` is almost right, but the bytes are reversed (`00 20`, should be `20 00` for Bit13).

```
byte[] flag = new byte[4];      
flag[0] = 0x30;
flag[1] = 0x30;
flag[2] = 0x32;
flag[3] = 0x30;

// Bytes to char, using the 'oversized' short so the numbers won't be out of range
short b1 = Short.parseShort(new String(new byte[]{flag[0], flag[1]}), 16);
short b2 = Short.parseShort(new String(new byte[]{flag[2], flag[3]}), 16);
char i = (char) (b1 | (b2 << 8));

// Print contents as binary string
System.out.println(String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0'));

// Output: 0010000000000000

// Check if 14'th bit is set (at index 13)
boolean isSet = ((i & (1 << 13)) != 0);

System.out.println(isSet); // true
```

You can use that method to check each bit. Just replace the `13` with the index you want to check.

---

I'm using a `char` here since that will print a little nicer. You could use a `short`, but whenever you convert that to an `int` (which can happen implicitly), the value gets padded with `1`'s if the most significant bit was set, because it's a *signed* type. `char` is *unsigned* however, so it doesn't have that behaviour.

Comment: According to my example `0x30 0x30 0x32 0x30`, the only bit set is Bit13.  Why many bits are `1` in your result?

Comment: @Sithu It was just an example... but I finally figured out how your conversion is supposed to work. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. That almost works. However, when I turn on all Bits, the value is `FFFF` equivalent to `0x46 0x46 0x46 0x46` and it throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"FFFF" Radix:16 at java.lang.Short.parseShort(Unknown Source)`. The same error for `FF7F` when all bits on except Bit15 off.

Comment: @Sithu watch out - if the value is 0xFF7F if only bit 15 is not set - the bytes are swapped - the current bit structure would be [7-0][15-8]...

Comment: And to prevent the `java.lang.NumberFormatException` change `short` to `int` or `long`...

Comment: @Sithu Hmm, it looks like java is having some problems since a ```short``` is technically a signed integer type. I found a solution using ```char```, which is 16 bit _unsigned_. See updated answer.

Comment: @JornVernee That works great! This new answer don't need to reverse bytes, right?

Comment: @Sithu Nope, that already happens with ```(b1 | (b2 << 8))```. Where the second part gets put to the left of the first.

Comment: @JornVernee I accepted your answer though I need to get more understanding on your code. Thank you. :)